# Android 4.4 WifiScan result

Tags: android, wifi, android-4.4-kitkat

I created a small test android app to do a scan of the surrounding wifi networks.

When I run the app on my galaxy nexus( jellybean) the result returns:

```
( SSID, BSSID, Capabilities, level, timestamp).
```

However when I run the same app on my Nexus 5( KitKat) the result returns:

```
( SSID, BSSID, Capabilities, level, timestamp, distance (cm), distanceSd(cm) ).
```

I can't seem to find anything about distance in the android WiFi API documentation. Does anyone know whats going on ???

Answer (score 0):

If you check the ScanResult.java source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588%5E/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.java), you can verify that in one of the `ScanResult` constructors, there are `int distCm` and `int distSdCm` parameters, for distance (cm) and distanceSd(cm), respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Well noticed !

Android is probably already **updating its API** to a new revision on `IEEE 802.11`.

There is a new update to provide indoor positioning using **TriLateration**.
This new feature adds a timestamp on the package called `Fine Timing Measurement (FTM)`, providing the capability to estimate the distance from an AP to a receiver.

If you want more info, you should search for `IEEE 802.11 REVmc`:

http://www.ieee802.org/11/Reports/802.11_Timelines.htm

Comment: It seems the values are never populated as they are always "?(cm)" or -1, and the fields are not exposed, so I assume this has not been implemented yet. I'm testing on a Pixel 2.